# An extra { when importing a file

Tags: list-manipulation, import

I am trying to import data from a file.

```
{k0,{a0,b0,c0},{e0,f0,g0}}
{k1,{a1,b1,c1},{e1,f1,g1}}

MyList = Import[file, "Data"];
```

But I get a list with an extra "{"

```
MyList
```

> ```
> {{{k0,{a0,b0,c0},{e0,f0,g0}}
>  {{k1,{a1,b1,c1},{e1,f1,g1}}}}
> ```

How can I get this result?

```
MyList
```

> ```
> {{k0,{a0,b0,c0},{e0,f0,g0}}
>  {k1,{a1,b1,c1},{e1,f1,g1}}}
> ```

Thanks

Comment: Take a look at `ReadList` too.

Comment: What Mathematica returns depends on what file format you are importing. You should mention the specific format in the question (better yet, give a sample data file), or indicate it directly in the `Import` command.  `"Data"` doesn't specify a format.  It only specifies what Mathematica should read from the file.  So here you are letting Mathematica guess the format based on the file extension.  An import format would be `"Table"`, `"CSV"`, `"XLSX"`, etc.

Comment: In additional to the points made above you must respect the expression and evaluation rules of *Mathematica*.  The result you claim you want is probably incorrect; it will immediately evaluate to `{{k0 k1, {a0 a1, b0 b1, c0 c1}, {e0 e1, f0 f1, g0 g1}}}`.  This evaluation can be prevented with certain measures but I *strongly* suspect you need something else in actuality.  Please clarify your needs.  Is this file supposed to be imported as String data, or expressions as currently shown in the post?  How do you intend to use it?  How was the file originally produced?

Answer (score 2):

I have used [`ReadList`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReadList.html?q=ReadList) command,

```
MyList = ReadList[file];
```

And now, the result is right,

```
MyList
```

> ```
> {{k0,{a0,b0,c0},{e0,f0,g0}}
>  {k1,{a1,b1,c1},{e1,f1,g1}}}
> ```

Your information has helped me to find a simple solution.
Regards.

Answer (score 1):

```
MyList = Import[file, "Words"]
```

Answer (score 0):

You got unbalanced brackets, that is unexpected. The expected result is

```
{{"{k0,{a0,b0,c0},{e0,f0,g0}}"}, {"{k1,{a1,b1,c1},{e1,f1,g1}}"}}
```

To convert this list of string to list expression is:

```
ToExpression /@ Flatten[{{"{k0,{a0,b0,c0},{e0,f0,g0}}"}, {"{k1,{a1,b1,c1},{e1,f1,g1}}"}}]
(*{{k0, {a0, b0, c0}, {e0, f0, g0}}, {k1, {a1, b1, c1}, {e1, f1, g1}}}*)
```

The reason of my preference of using `"Data"` is that you can get the two lists automatically separated, if you use `"Plaintext"`, you have to add a step to replace that `"\n"` to `","`.
(I assumed you want to have two lists, not the product of two lists.)